# Conexão com API com tipo Basic Auth

Tags: c#

estou precisando conectar em uma API no MÉTODO HTTP GET com Basic Auth.
Peguei esse exemplo na net, ajustei mas ele não esta retornando nada.

string username = "179341";
                string password = "12CC97";

```
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
            string encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic" + encoded);
            request.ContentType = "application/xml";
            request.Method = "GET";
            HttpWebResponse response;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

onde estou errando?
agradeço deste já.

Comment: Não entendo de C# mas olhando seu código já vejo algumas coisas que podem ter dado errado, confirme o Method creio que deveria ser POST, lá linha onde você adiciona o header Authorization entre o Basic e a string encoded tem que ter um espaço em branco, então ficaria "Basic " + encoded. Tente aumentar o nível de verbosidade do seu log, com certeza está retornando algum erro ou dando algum erro, isso vai te ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente dessa maneira:

```
public string HttpRequest(string url, string username, string password)
    {
        string authInfo = username + ":" + password;
        authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));


        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Accept = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        string strResponse = "";
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            strResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();

        }

        return strResponse;
    }
```

Comment: Olá Gustavo.
Ele não me retorno nada.
O retorno seria em xml.
Acabei de colocar o usuário e senha errado e deu Não Autorizado.
Então ele esta autenticando.

Comment: Poderia postar o retorno do seu xml?

Comment: Coloque uma imagem dele